# PHP replace part of the URL in css file

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace relative url in my css files into my servers static URL.

For example, I have a CSS rule:

[/public/images...] or ['/public/images...'], or [../public/images...] or ['../public/images...'] and I need to replace all of these urls into my static server CDN:

```
/public/images... -> //static.mysite.com/public/images...
'/public/images...' -> '//static.mysite.com/public/images...'
../public/images... -> //static.mysite.com/public/images...
```

I wrote a regular expression to do this, but it doesn't work with '../' at the beginning of the URL. Here it is:

```
$fileRawContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
$replacedContent = preg_replace('/\(\'?(.*(\.\.)?\/public\/images.*)\'?\)/', "($staticServer$1)", $fileRawContent);
```

This works only for /public/images but not for ../public/images...

Please advice how to do like I said.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PHP `preg_replace` does what you describe:

```
preg_replace(
    "/(')?(\.\.)?(\/public\/images.*'?)/"
    , "$1$staticServer$3" // notice the $1 at the start, $3 at the end
    , $fileRawContent
);
```

Test run:

```
$staticServer = '//static.mysite.com';
$fileRawContent = "'../public/images...'";
$replacedContent = preg_replace("/(')?(\.\.)?(\/public\/images.*'?)/", "$1$staticServer$3", $fileRawContent);
print $replacedContent;
```

Outputs:

```
'//static.mysite.com/public/images...'
```

Likewise:

```
/public/images...   -> //static.mysite.com/public/images...
'/public/images...' -> '//static.mysite.com/public/images...'
../public/images... -> //static.mysite.com/public/images...
```

---

*Regular Expression Explanation:*

```
(')?(\.\.)?(\/public\/images.*'?)
```

We start with a single quote in parenthesis. This allows us to 1) make it optional with the question mark `?` and 2) capture it for interpolation into our replacement parameter. Then we wrap two periods `.` in parenthesis and make them optional `?`. (These are also captured into the variable `$2` but we don't use it.) Finally we capture the (properly escaped) public images path followed by zero or more characters `.*` and an optional `?` single quote.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use str_replace?

```
$replaced_content = str_replace(
array('[/public_images/1/', '[/public_images/2/', '[/public_images/3/'),
array('[//static.mysite.com/public/images/1/', '[//static.mysite.com/public/images/2/', '[//static.mysite.com/public/images/3/'), $file_raw_content);
```

Comment: I don't want to use str_replace because of when I will execute this script next time at the same file - it will replace '/public/images' again and I will get something like this: '//static.mysite.com///static.mysite.com/public/images'

Comment: Well, you could include the starting delimeter [ and maybe the ending delimeter ] and you could combine like @diggersworld mentioned with strpos if you have performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be quite intensive. You could do this with something easier such as `strpos().`

http://php.net/strpos

```
if (strpos($filepath, 'public/images') !== FALSE) 
{
    $filepath = '//static.mysite.com/public/images...';
}
```

Maybe combine this with @juge answer so that you aren't always searching for the three variants.